# How do I save a time window in Flink to a text file?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am starting to work in ApacheFlink in Java.

My goal is to consume an ApacheKafka theme in a one minute time window and that will apply very basic information and record the result of each window in a file.

So far I managed to apply a text transformation simplification to what I receive, I should use apply or process to write the file the result of the window I am somewhat lost.

This is my Code so far

```
package myflink;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple3;
import org.apache.flink.shaded.akka.org.jboss.netty.channel.ExceptionEvent;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.windowing.AllWindowFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.windowing.ProcessAllWindowFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.windowing.ProcessWindowFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.windowing.WindowFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.watermark.Watermark;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.TimeWindow;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject;
public class BatchJob {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment  env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
        properties.setProperty("group.id", "test");
        properties.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
        FlinkKafkaConsumer consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer("topic-basic-test", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties);
        DataStream<String> data = env.addSource(consumer);
        data.flatMap(new JSONparse()).timeWindowAll(Time.minutes(1))."NEXT ??" .print()
        System.out.println("Hola usuario 2");
        env.execute("Flink Batch Java API Skeleton");
    }
    public static class JSONparse implements FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, String>> {
        @Override
        public void flatMap(String s, Collector<Tuple2<String, String>> collector) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(s);
            s = s + "ACA PODES JUGAR NDEAH";
            collector.collect(new Tuple2<String,String>("M",s));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result of each one minute window to go to its own file, you can look at using the [`StreamingFileSink`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/streamfile_sink.html) with one minute buckets -- which should do what you are looking for, or come very close.

I think you'll actually end up with a directory for each window containing a file from each parallel instance of the window -- but as you using `timeWindowAll`, which does not operate in parallel, there will be only one file per bucket, unless the results are so large that the file rolls over.

By the way, doing JSON parsing in a FlatMap will perform rather poorly because this will end up instantiating a new parser for each event, which will in turn cause considerable GC activity. It would be better to use a RichFlatMap and create one parser in the open() method that you can reuse for each event. And even better still, use a `JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema` rather than a `SimpleStringSchema`, and have the kafka connector handle the json parsing for you.